# Flutter Provider Listen to a condition within provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a provider with states:

```
enum RemoteJSONState { parsing, parsed, failedToParse }
```

In one my widgets, I listen to all the changes with

```
class RemoteJSONStateProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  set remoteJSONState(RemoteJSONState givenState) {
    if (givenState == _remoteJSONState) {
      return;
    }

    _remoteJSONState = givenState;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

In another widget of mine, I only want to listen to "parsed" state. This is because initially my widget is running information based on local storage. When remote data is fetched it will update itself with the fetched info. If fetching fails, I simply dont want to build my widget and I want to use the local information available. Hence, I dont want a widget rebuild.

Here is what i tried so far.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    RemoteJSONStateProvider =
        Provider.of<RemoteJSONStateProvider>(context);
  }
```

The problem is my widget gets rebuild if RemoteJSONStateProvider states is changed to "failedToParse". How may I only listen for a condition? which is

```
RemoteJSONStateProvider._remoteJSONState == RemoteJSONState.parsed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers didnt satisfy me as I need to keep the old function for my other widget. After an hour of research, I made a Selector widget to do my needs.

```
Selector<RemoteJSONStateProvider, RemoteJSONState>(
      builder: (context, remoteJSONStateProvider, child) {
        print("rebuild");
        return Text('build');
      },
      selector: (buildContext, remoteJSONStateProvider) =>
          remoteJSONStateProvider.remoteJSONState,
      shouldRebuild: (prev, next) =>
          prev != RemoteJSONState.parsed && next == RemoteJSONState.parsed,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a local variable called `isParsedStateChange` which will notify only when parsed state is called.

```
class RemoteJSONStateProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isParsedStateChange = false;
  get isParsedStateChange => _isParsedStateChange;

  set parsedJSONState(RemoteJSONState givenState) {
    _isParsedStateChange = (RemoteJSONState. parsed == givenState) 
    if(_isParsedStateChange) {
      notifyListeners();
     }
  }
}
```

**Use like**

```
RemoteJSONStateProvider =
        Provider.of<RemoteJSONStateProvider>(context).isParsedStateChange;
```

**Note:** Create a separate method which will set parsed state

Comment: I want to keep the original function I am using, since a different widget depends on it, If i keep the old method with this new one, wouldnt my widget get rebuild since old method is using notifyListeners()?

Comment: it should not as you are listening to variable.

Comment: other listeners would still be notified since notifyListeners(); is called

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

@jitsm555 is 8 seconds faster than me, has a better code.

---

You can define another variable in the provider like this:

```
    bool isParsed = false;
```

And set it in your condition:

```
  class RemoteJSONStateProvider with ChangeNotifier {
    set remoteJSONState(RemoteJSONState givenState) {
      if (givenState == _remoteJSONState) {
        isParsed = true;
        return;
      }

      _remoteJSONState = givenState;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

After that, you can listen only isParsed condition:

```
   RemoteJSONStateProvider.isParsed
```